# How to send post request with oAuth 1.0 using retrofit?

Tags: java, android, api, oauth, retrofit

I want to send post request with retrofit with additional things like **oAuth 1.0, Consumer Key and Consumer secret** [Image for explain briefly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6RIC.png)

and I want to send data with `raw` inside `body`

**Request i want to send**:

```
InputFormat=application/json&InputData={
   "provider":"fb",
   "profileId":"ashok",
   "email":"ashok.kom",
   "MobileNo":"91-868",
   "FirstName":"Ashok",
   "LastName":"Komara",
   "gender":"M",
   "loginId":"ashok",
   "subscribeToOffers":"true"
}
```

**My Api service**

```
public interface APIService {

    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Consumer_Key: HHAKRMFG",
    "Signature_Method: HMAC-SHA1",
    "OAuth_Version: 1.0",
    "Consumer_Secret: DPNQGUX1TKRYGWJOPH5DBLRB"})
    @POST("LoginWithThirdPartyProvider")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<ResponseList> savePost(@Field("provider") String provider,
                                @Field("profileId") String profileId,
                                @Field("email") String email,
                                @Field("MobileNo") String MobileNo,
                                @Field("FirstName") String FirstName,
                                @Field("LastName") String LastName,
                                @Field("gender") String gender,
                                @Field("loginId") String loginId,
                                @Field("subscribeToOffers") String subscribeToOffers);
}
```

[image: My header in postman]

Answer (score 2):

I have got got a way to do this or can say **I have got answer of my question**

[This](https://github.com/rameshvoltella/WoocommerceAndroidOAuth1) library help me to use `retrofit` with `oAuth 1.0`

In the mid I got lot of **minor errors** which are easily resolve by **searching on Internet**

If you are using this library don't forget to add
`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />`

in you `<application` tag